# Proper clamping of MC in old work box

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I'm adding two 20A circuits with one duplex receptacle each in a 2 gang box. I'm using an old work metal box, and 12/2 MC cable. It is my first time using MC cable, and I just wanted to know if the clamping looks OK. I had to use MC because part of the cable is going through a closet. I did use the red anti-short bushings. The metal boxes came with integrated MC clamps. This receptacle will be used to plug space heaters in, so I want to make sure it is done well. I used commercial grade 20A receptacles (space heaters are designed for 15A circuits). I used my torque screwdriver set to 14 in.lbs.

Do you see any issues with this install?

[image: Clamp for old metal work box]
[image: Box with clamps and MC]
[image: MC clamp closeup]
[image: Second MC clamp closeup]
[image: Box wired up with outlets]
[image: Detailed view of outlet wiring]
[image: Another detailed view of outlet wiring]
[image: Torque screwdriver]

Comment: Doubleplusgood! You could make valuable instructional materials with shots like that.

Comment: You have excellent photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hire you for my company! Everything looks done very well.  The only suggestion I have is to wrap the terminals with electrical tape, which is common practice when using metal boxes. Very nice job!

Comment: Thanks for the review and suggestion to wrap with electrical tape. I was planning to use an Ideal Armourband to insulate the terminals. I have done it with tape, but it tends to be a bit messy if you have to remove it in the future. I was glad to see the Leviton outlets had one of the side screws tightened out of the box, and one open for wiring. I worry about loose screws touching metal boxes.